# members_data.dob may not be NULL in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

Using Django 1.4 in my app I defined a model called **Member** and another called **Data**.Every member has basic like **ID** and it is related to a Data object that contains additional variables describing the "member".

I had initially created the member model without specifying that the **dob** variable could be NULL. I have since then changed this to allow for blank or null but I was still getting the `members_data.dob may not be NULL` error.

I thought it was because I needed to run a `syncdb` command, which I did, however this did not fix the problem.

```
dob = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
```

Any ideas? Thanks

ps. If you want to get an overall picture of what I am trying to implement please refer to: [Can I use JSON data to add new objects in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18724863/can-i-use-json-data-to-add-new-objects-in-django)

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syncdb command only creates tables if they do not exist. It does not handle migrations for you. You have a few options:

1. If there is no important data in the table, drop the table and run syncdb again to recreate it.
2. Update the column to allow null in a db shell. The correct command depends on which database you are using.
3. Use a migration tool, like South.

To drop the table in sqlite:

Open a dbshell

```
./manage.py dbshell
```

Drop the table

```
drop table <tablename>
```

Comment: Thanks! Ok that was my question. I wasn't sure if this would signify I need a migration. So pretty much syncdb just creates the database tables, any other changes to it will require migration, no exception, right?

Comment: I am using SQLite. Any ideas how can I drop the table since I dont have too much information in it and would also like to know how to do it in the shell in case I need it in the future. Thanks so much.

Comment: I've added instructions to drop the table. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007014/alter-column-in-sqlite) about altering columns in sqlite.