# Does setattr() method creates a temporary object?

Tags: python, django, django-models

This is in reference to a great answer [Can I use JSON data to add new objects in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18724863/can-i-use-json-data-to-add-new-objects-in-django)

However I am particularly intrigued by how this component works:  **member, _ = Member.objects.get_or_create(name = self.name)**  Please look at the context and the statement below.

```
 class Member(models.Model):
        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.record

        def was_published_recently(self):
            return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
        was_published_recently.admin_order_field = 'pub_date'
        was_published_recently.boolean = True
        was_published_recently.short_description = 'Entered recently?'

        record = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date')


   class Data(models.Model):

    member = models.ForeignKey(Member)
    dob = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    event = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

        **member, _ = Member.objects.get_or_create(name = self.name)**
        # can update member here with other fields that relate to them
        self.member = member
        super(Data, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


//----

        json = [{" Record": 12345,
    "Name": "Joe",
    "Event":" Initial task completed",
    "TeamID": 12345,
    "IndiviualID":"",
    "Description":" Just a description",
    "Date": "1/3/13 9:00"},{" Record": 5555,
    "Name": "Jane",
    "Event":" A different task completed",
    "TeamID": 9999,
    "IndiviualID":"",
    "Description":" Just another description",
    "Date": "1/13/13 6:00"}]

        for item in json:

            d = Data()

            for k,v in item.iteritems():
                **setattr(d, k.lower(), v)**

            d.save()
```

Notice that self.name is technically accessing the name variable in my Data Object which in reality the name variable does not exist on my Data Object model definition. So this is the core of my question: How does this code works? It made me think there is some kind of temporary Data Object that does in fact contains Data.name (aka self.name) before it is discarded since it is in the JSON representation of the data but not on my Data object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that's not how it works at all.

Python objects are dynamic. You can define whatever attributes you like on them at any point. It doesn't matter whether you do `setattr(d, "name", "foo")` or `d.name = foo`, the result is exactly the same: the `d` instance gains an attribute `name`, whether or not it previously had one, and whether or not there is a definition in the class that mentions it.

Django models add their own special syntax for defining the fields that they store in the database, but underneath that they're just Python objects, so you can dynamically define extra attributes on them as much as you like.

Comment: So you can add the attributes to the Python object but obviously you wont be able to add it to the database unless you told Django models about it (i.e. defined it). Right? Thanks! Awesome explanation.

Comment: See [Data model](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html) in the docs for details, but basically, `setattr(d, "name", "foo")` just resolves to `d.__dict__["name"] = "foo"`. (You can customize it to do different things, in a few different ways, but the default is to just use a `__dict__`.)

Comment: Very useful python feature